# c# ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to display modal from c#, but it keeps returning ReferenceError: openModal is not defined

```
<script>
    function openModal() {
        $("#modal-reset").modal('show');
    }
</script>


    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "modal-reset", "$('#modal-reset').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});", true);
    //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "$('#modal-reset').modal('show');", true);
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "Script", "<script>openModal();</script>", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Script", "openModal();", true);
}
```

If I where in your shoes, I define this code block in Shared.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

Worked after adding this to the `head` tag (I was formally loading it in the `body` tag)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

then I added another script:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can put de calling of modal inside of script, this way:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "MyScript", "$('#ModalID').modal('show');", true);
```

This works for me in my projects.

I hope works for you too!